# using evaluate in lotusscript

Tags: lotusscript, evaluate

I tried to get current user roles by using Lotus Script. And I'm using "Evaluate" method to get it so that I can used along with Formula Language. Below is the code

```
Dim test as Variant 

test = Evaluate("@UserRoles")       

If  test = "[Administrator]" Then                   
     Print "admin"
Else
     Print "Not admin"
End If
```

But then, when I tried to run the code, I get this error : "type mismatch in method CheckOperand: Unknown found, Unknown expected"

Can someone who expert in Lotus Script give me your thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluate is returning an array, so you need to perform the check accordingly.

```
Dim roles as Variant 
roles = Evaluate("@UserRoles") 
Forall r in roles
    If r = "[Administrator]" Then
        Print "Admin"
    End If
End ForAll
```

Comment: You could also do the check within the evaluate statement for a more succinct test e.g. hasAdminRole = Implode(Evaluate(|@Contains(@UserRoles; "[Administrator]")|))

Comment: @Jon: True, but I am sure that in a real life application, you want to check for several different user roles, and then my code is more flexible. Of course, if you are looking for more than two or three values, a **Select Case** statement is better than **If-Then**.